# Linux Cronjob not running powershell script, but the script is able to run in terminal

Tags: linux, powershell, cron

I have a PowerShell Script that updates a database table. I would like to set this up in the Cronjob to run daily. However it doesnt seem to work in the cronjob. At the moment I have setting it forward a couple minutes so that I dont have to wait.

CronTab:

```
* * * * * pswh -File "/home/administrator/PowerShellScripts/Update-Set-Table.ps1"
```

Terminal:

```
pswh -File "/home/administrator/PowerShellScripts/Update-Set-Table.ps1"
```

Working perfectly when I run that command in the terminal but it doesnt seem to be running from the cronjob.

Comment: Try running a bash script (.sh) file with that cmd in it. Make sure to lock the file down to the owner of the cron job for security reasons. Please note this is a bash question more so than a powershell question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to specify the full path to the executable `pwsh`. you can do so by using `which APPNAME` in a terminal.

```
which pwsh
```

then change the line in your crontab accordingly. for me the working result looks like this:

```
* * * * * /snap/bin/pswh -File "/home/administrator/PowerShellScripts/Update-Set-Table.ps1"
```

Answer (score 0):

Cron's lack of environment has this side effect: the working directory changes. In my case I was writing to a file I expected to be in the script's directory which was being created & written to nicely in $HOME.

The script's directory is held in the PoSh variable `$PSScriptRoot`

PoSh has a symlink at `/usr/bin/pwsh` so the full path is not necessary (for me anyway)

The current (Vixie) cron allows standard variables which can be used for paths. Check the author in `man crontab`

If you're script has a `#!/usr/bin/pwsh` shebang & is executable it executes like any script without specifying 'pwsh'

BTW if you're displaying to screen, say a dialog, the cron job must be prefaced with `env DISPLAY=:0`(or some other number) in order to display. eg `env DISPLAY=:0 pwsh $ScriptHome/DiskFull-WereGoingToCrash.ps1 -display`